# Euler class and the real homological class of the fiber in an orientable sphere bundle

Tags: fibre-bundles, homology

In the paper *Foliations transverse to the fiber of a bundle*, Plante considers the following example. Let $p:E\longrightarrow B$ a orientable fiber bundle with fiber $\mathbb{S}^k$. We have the Gysin cohomology sequence (real coefficients)  associated 
$$ H^{k}(B) {\longrightarrow}^{p^*} H^{k}(E)  \longrightarrow  H^{0}(B) \longrightarrow^\Psi H^{k+1}(B),$$
where $\Psi(1)$ is the Euler class of the bundle. Plante made the affirmation: *the 
fiber is null-homologous in $H_k(E)$ iff $p*$ is surjective which is true iff the Euler class is nonzero*.  By the exactness of the Gysin sequence, it's easy to see that $p^*$ is surjective if, and only if, the Euler class is nonzero.  As the coefficients are the real numbers, we have that $p^*$ is the transpose of the map $p_*:H_k(E)\longrightarrow H_k(B)$ and,  $p^*$ being surjective implies $p_*$ injective. Follows that $p^*$ being surjective implies that the class of the fiber is null in $H_k(E)$ since that is always true that $p_*[\mathbb{S}^k]=0$. I don't know how to complete the converse, to show that when the fiber is null homologous then the map $p_*$ is injective.

Ps. If the fiber is null homologous, then the map $p_*:\pi_k(E)\longrightarrow \pi_k(B)$ is an isomorphism (follows by the homotopy sequence of a fibration, page 376, Algebraic topology - Hatcher). I don't know if this says something about the map $p_*:H_k(E)\longrightarrow H_k(B)$.